# Querying a query

Tags: sql

I've more experience using Access where I would build up my analysis in small parts and query each new view.

I'm not trying to do something that must be simple in SQL.

If I have a query of the format:

```
SELECT events.people, COUNT(events.eventType) AS usersAndEventCount
FROM theDB.events
WHERE event_id = 884
GROUP BY people
```

And I then want to query usersAndEventCount
like so:

```
Select usersAndEventCount.people, usersAndEventCount.events
FROM [from where actually?]
```

Tried from:

```
usersAndEventCount;
events
theDB.events
```

This must seem very basic to SQL users on SO. But in my mind it's much easier to breakdown the larger query into these sub queries.

How would I query usersAndEventCount in the same query?

Comment: I typically build a table and insert my intial query into it, then I query that table or build as many tables as I need and query them together.

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator can I query the query within the query though? Rather than making new tables?

Comment: @Doug Firr Like `select * from (select * from) t` ? Yes

Comment: If the sets are related, join the tables on events.people and usersAndEventCount.people (I think), so that the columns from the second table appear along with the first.  If they are totally different, you won't be able to combine them.  It's 2 different sets.

Comment: @Bharadwaj thanks for the comment but I don;t follow?

Comment: @DougFirr see the answer posted by a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement "*then want to query usersAndEventCount*" does not make sense because `usersAndEventCount` is a *column* - at least in your first example. You can not "query" a column.

But from the example you have given it seems you want something like this:

```
Select usersAndEventCount.people, usersAndEventCount.events
FROM (
  SELECT events.people, 
         COUNT(events.eventType) AS as events
  FROM theDB.events
  WHERE event_id = 884
  GROUP BY people  
) as usersAndEventCount
```

This is called a "derived table" in SQL

Comment: So in your example is the derived table just everything in the parenthesis? IS there no way to create a shorthand for that in the same way we can create a column using AS?

Comment: @DougFirr: correct - the derived table is the part between the parenthesis. And the `as usersAndEventCount` part gives it a name. The keyword `AS` is used to define a column alias or a table alias. If you want to re-use this select statement in different (unrelated) queries you need to create a view.

Comment: So, rather than posting a separate "child" question to this may I ask too the following: If in my first code block in my original question I deleted the "AS usersAndEventCount" and placed it underneath the GROUP BY line so it was the last line - would that make it a table within this query? Could I then query it as it's own table further down the query?

Comment: @DougFirr: no. It only becomes a derived table if you use it as shown in my example.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Shame, so there is no way to define my temporary tables to be used within the query at the outset and then build upon them. Well now I know. Thanks for all your help on this question

Comment: @DougFirr: again: if you want a "re-usable" query, create a view.

Comment: @DougFirr The `AS` keyword is **optional** so this answer is identical to mine. It neither creates a column nor a temporary table, it simply gives the sub-query a name (i.e. an alias), so you can use this name in the main query to access the columns of the sub-query. And to your point "*so there is no way to define my temporary tables*", yes there is a way to do so, but not in pure SQL. Different databases have different implementation for how to create temporary tables. However in your scenario, a view or stored procedure is more suitable than a temporary table.

Answer (score 3):

In pure SQL, you can use nested queries (AKA sub-queries). Just enclose your first query in `()` brackets, so your query will look like this:

```
Select usersAndEventCount.people, usersAndEventCount.events
FROM (SELECT events.people, COUNT(events.eventType) AS events
      FROM theDB.events
      WHERE event_id = 884
      GROUP BY people) usersAndEventCount
```

Alternatively, to save the first query and reuse it in several places like you were doing in Access, you can save it as a View or Stored Procedure depending on the database system you're using. If you want an example, let me know the database system you're using.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Racil. I guess I was hoping that it'd be simpler than that but, from the answer from horse_with_no_name it seems that when I write AS in SQL it becomes a column.
I'm not sure if I should stick to what I'm used to with Access and create lots of tables or if I should try to query everything at once. The later would seem to be the SQl way?

Comment: @DougFirr It depends on what you want to achieve. Putting it altogether in one query like above, is slightly better for the performance, but the difference can be negligible depending on the database engine optimization. On the other hand, if you find yourself rewriting the sub-query several times in different main queries, then you can save your efforts by creating a View or Stored Procedure and call it in all those different places.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure per 100%, because at the moment i can not test. But I think it should work. 
uaec is the alias for the subquery. This alias you can use in the main query

```
Select uaec.people, uaec.usersAndEventCount
FROM (SELECT events.people, COUNT(events.eventType) AS usersAndEventCount
FROM theDB.events
WHERE event_id = 884
GROUP BY people) uaec
```

Comment: Thanks but I think my understanding of what AS does has thrown the question off.
I tried querying a sub query along the lines of your example but with no joy.